# Installing K3S offline faild with error: starting kubernetes: preparing server: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I now install a k3s on:

1. A centos7 with arm64;
2. A mysql8.0;

I have disabled:
firewall
selinux
swap

I have modified /etc/hosts;

I have installed docker-ce;

I have downloaded:

1. https://get.k3s.io to install.sh
2. k3s-airgap-images-arm64.tar to the right place "/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/images/"
3. chmod +x k3s-arm64 and move to "/usr/local/bin/k3s".

I'm quite sure the mysql connection is ok.Then I use: INSTALL_K3S_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true INSTALL_K3S_EXEC='server --docker --datastore-endpoint="mysql://root:root@tcp(172.16.149.139:3306)/k3s"' ./install.sh

But I always got error shows in journalctl:

```
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 k3s[16058]: time="2020-11-19T11:05:52.883415201+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 k3s[16058]: time="2020-11-19T11:05:52.884004317+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:05:52 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:05:57 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:05:57 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:05:57 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 k3s[16086]: time="2020-11-19T11:05:58.341115144+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 k3s[16086]: time="2020-11-19T11:05:58.345448686+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:05:58 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 k3s[16114]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:03.855567834+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 k3s[16114]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:03.856344291+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:03 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:08 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:06:08 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:08 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 k3s[16142]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:09.430387037+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 k3s[16142]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:09.431185565+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:09 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 k3s[16193]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:14.888534204+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 k3s[16193]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:14.889537923+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:14 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:19 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:06:19 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:19 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 k3s[16221]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:20.442535396+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 k3s[16221]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:20.443421344+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:20 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:24 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:24 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 k3s[16336]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:25.168513665+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 k3s[16336]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:25.168946929+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:25 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: Starting Lightweight Kubernetes...
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 k3s[16363]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:30.645875517+08:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.19.3+k3s3 (0e4fbfef)"
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 k3s[16363]: time="2020-11-19T11:06:30.649172179+08:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: creating storage endpoint: building kine: dial tcp\\: unknown network tcp\\"
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: Unit k3s.service entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:06:30 k3s01 systemd[1]: k3s.service failed.
```

I really don't know what's going on, need help!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally , I found that I must use K3S_DATASTORE_ENDPOINT='mysql://xxxxxxx' not INSTALL_K3S_EXEC='xxx  --datastore-endpoint="mysql://xxxxxx"' to avoid this!But I don't know what's on earth of it

Comment: I've created an issue and there was a right answer.
https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/2552